# Apostrophe usage in "your order's been dispatched"

Tags: apostrophe, contractions

> Your order's been dispatched.

Is this contraction (not to indicate plural, but as a contraction of "order has") correct?  Or would it be better to just simply write:

> Your order has been dispatched.

I've looked through quite a few examples, but couldn't quite decide so thought I'd ask the community.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's correct. Written English tends to be more formal, though, and I would tend to write *has been*, but say *it's*. (It's not possessive, though. It's just a contraction for has, as it's is for it is.)

The New York Times is a well respected newspaper, which is fairly conservative in their English. Plus, it's written, which is more formal than spoken. However, in looking through some of their articles, I found:

> - What if It's All Been a Big Fat Lie? - New York Times
> - So Long, It's Been Good to Know You - NYTimes.com
> - It's been a year since Citi Bike started in New York City... NYTimes.com

But even there, it tends to appear in blogs, in quoting someone, or in well known phrases (*it's been good to know you.*)

Comment: I think 'it has been' tends to be an established exception to your general rule, especially where, as in your examples, 'it' has no antecedent, either real or clearly implied.